# weird behaviour on stage resize

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, stage

As soon I hover the blue mc, the navigation with the pics expands. 
Whenever the mouse is over the navigation, the navigation stays expanded.
As soon the mouse leaves the navigation, it moves back underneath the blue mc.

When it has been loaded, it does like it should.
A resizing of the stage centers the whole parent-mc.

The problem: A stage-resize causes that the MOUSE_OUT event of the navigation fires, even though the mouse has not left the navigation-mc.

[image]

```
private function onNavOver(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        this._bluemc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,onMouseAreaBottomOver);
        this._bluemc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,onMouseAreaBottomOut);
        TweenLite.to(this._navigation,0.7,{y:this._offsetY,ease:Expo.easeInOut});
        TweenLite.killTweensOf(this._navigation,false); 
    }
private function onNavOut(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        this._bluemc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,onMouseAreaBottomOver,false,0,true);
        this._bluemc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,onMouseAreaBottomOut,false,0,true);
        TweenLite.to(this._navigation,0.7,{y:this._initialY,ease:Expo.easeInOut});


    }
```

the code above are the event-functions called when being over or out of the navigation.
The bluemc events will be removed in order to keep the navigation opened. I think here is a potential conflict: the MOUSE_OUT event of the blue mc could be fired before removed(onNavOver). But the strange thing is that only when I resized the stage, the failure appears. The navigation moves back even when the mouse is withing the navigation.

Comment: How are you resizing the stage without rolling off the navigation?  If it's being done with code could you post it?

Comment: yes, when resizing the stage, the navigation moves back. But then when resized and when I expand the navigation again, The mouse-Area is somehow not the same again. I could imagine there is a confusion between the MouseEvents: Leaving the bluemc is fired at same time when I'm over the Navigation(onNavOver)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it:
Event-Confusion: Solved through adding ROLL_OVER/OUT events instead of MOUSE_OVER/OUT
And there was a invisible MC set: mc.y= stage.stageHeight -> On stageResize its position was overlapping the navigation because it was not updated.